# How to use Apple Mail as default email program in Windows 8 running under Parallels?

Tags: mail.app, email, parallels-desktop

I am using Microsoft OneNote, Visual Studio 2013 and Visio 2013 under Windows 8.1 running on Parallels 9 on my iMac. All of these have support for sharing content via e-mail. 
Is there a way to configure the host's Apple Mail application as the default application under the virtual Windows? Is there maybe some kind of proxy EXE that would fire up the Apple Mail app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible!
First things first: I have Parallels 8, but I expect this setting to not have moved significantly since.

1. Open your virtual machine's configuration
2. Go to options
3. Select "Programms"
4. On the right side you'll see "E-Mail" and a drop down list where you can select "Open in Mac" or along these lines.

Mind you, I have a German installation, so this is freely translated by myself, the wording might be slightly different.

Comment: Works. Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2013 still wants "Outlook" to be installed explicitly.

Comment: That's a dependency or artificial requirement set by Microsoft, hence nothing will fix this from the Mac side of things.

Comment: At least it's working in OneNote now.